# How to Remove Certain Words only if it is additional keyword without deleting keyword duplication

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

```
id  keyword
1   transfer
2   atm transfer
3   atm
4   ulta transfer
5   transfer transfer
```

I want to delete `transfer` word if no one words left, but if only `transfer` word left, the word is still remain, other word is `atm`, but if only `atm`  and `transfer` left, we select `atm`, if keyword appear multiple times, please make it once

Here's the code

```
df['keyword_2'] = df['keyword'].mask(df['keyword'] != 'transfer', df['keyword'].str.replace('transfer', '').str.strip())
```

My the output

```
id  keyword            keyword_2
1   transfer           transfer
2   atm transfer       atm
3   atm                atm
4   ulta transfer      transfer
5   transfer transfer
```

My the expected output

```
id  keyword            keyword_2
1   transfer           transfer
2   atm transfer       atm
3   atm                atm
4   ulta transfer      transfer
5   transfer transfer  transfer
```

Hopefully, this question is clear enough

Comment: For index `4` row is not last `ulta` in column `keyword_2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare values splitted by whitespace with sets and set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df['keyword'].str.split().apply(set) != set(['transfer'])
df['keyword1'] = np.where(mask, df['keyword'].str.replace('transfer', '').str.strip(), 
                                'transfer')
print (df)
   id            keyword  keyword1
0   1           transfer  transfer
1   2       atm transfer       atm
2   3                atm       atm
3   4      ulta transfer      ulta
4   5  transfer transfer  transfer
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
def remove_transfer(x):
    l = x.split()
    if len(l) == 1:
        return x
    #l = [el for el in l if el != 'transfer']
    l.remove('transfer')
    return ' '.join(l)

df['keyword_2'] = df['keyword'].apply(remove_transfer)

id  keyword       keyword_2
1   transfer      transfer
2   atm transfer  atm
3   atm           atm
4   ulta transfer ulta
5   transfer
```

Comment: Sorry, I 'm improving my questions

Answer (score 2):

Using `Series.apply` with a lambda function:

```
pat = 'transfer'
df['keyword2'] = df['keyword'].apply(lambda x: x if x == pat else x.replace(pat, '', 1).strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

So I can imagine that the word you want to replace can be more than two times in your data, than you can solve your case with the following function and then use `.apply` like the following:

Imagine your data looks like this:

```
    keyword
0   transfer
1   atm transfer
2   atm
3   ulta transfer
4   transfer transfer transfer
```

As we see, index 4 contains your keyword 3x.

So we need a more robuust solution like the following:

```
# Function to remove a word
def remove_word(x, word):
    if x == word:
        return x
    elif x.count(word) > 2:
        return x.replace(word, '', x.count(word)-1)
    else: 
        return x.replace(word, '', 1)

# Apply the function
df['keyword_2'] = df.keyword.apply(lambda x: remove_word(x, 'transfer'))
```

**Output**

```
    keyword                     keyword_2
0   transfer                    transfer
1   atm transfer                atm
2   atm                         atm
3   ulta transfer               ulta
4   transfer transfer transfer  transfer
```